# Silverstripe middleware not working

Tags: php, middleware, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I'm adding new empty middleware and getting an error:
"[Emergency] Uncaught BadMethodCallException: Session cannot be accessed until it's started"

```
<?php

use SilverStripe\Control\Middleware\HTTPMiddleware;
use SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest;

class MyMiddleware implements HTTPMiddleware
{
    public function process(HTTPRequest $request, callable $delegate){
        $response = $delegate($request);
        return $response;
    }
}


---
Name: myrequestprocessors
After:
  - 'requestprocessors'
---
SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector:
  SilverStripe\Control\Director:
    properties:
      Middlewares:
        - '%$MyMiddleware'
```

recipe-cms v1.0.3

Is there a workaround to prevent this error and make middleware work?

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was typo in other yml file:

```
SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector:
SilverStripe\Assets\Image_Backend:
  properties:
    Quality: 80
```

There was wrong offset in settings.